# Google Play doesn't update my app's download stats

Tags: google-play

About 5 days ago my app passed 570 downloads but my badge still shows 100 downloads on google play, Isn't 5 days too long to update these stats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are supposed to update every 24 hours., stats which is displayed in developer console is not reliable, they often stop updating for few days.

I'd suggest you to integrate Google Analytics for Mobile, localitics or any other framework if you want good statistics.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently so I contacted Google Play developers support and they clarified the issue.

As it turned out, the number shown in Developer's console statistics "New users acquired" and on the "Installs" badge in Google Play are computed using different algorithms. The first one shows raw installs while the second one shows the somehow corrected data. In particular, install metrics may be discounted or even removed entirely if Google detects fraudulent installs.